# Get the View from a Preference to add a KeyListener

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

My objective is get the `View` from my custom `Preference` to add a `KeyListener` who listens the key events of right and left, and if the user send a left/right event when the Seekbar is selected, it will move the pointer to the left/right.

[image: My SeekBar Preference]

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a custom Preference, you can override the [onBindView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#onBindView%28android.view.View%29) method, which receives the `View` object mapped to your `Prefence` instance. With that, you can add the corresponding listeners.